# Problems with KeyListeners in my jar file

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror, keylistener

I have made an Asteroids game in java, and I have recently attempted to export it to a jar. Before exporting it to a jar everything worked correctly and still continues to do so but after creating the jar, and trying to run it, it fails to run and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: AsteroidPanel$Key
```

This is the text I put into the terminal to create the jar, and I am sure that these are all the classes and resources for my game. AsteroidDriver.txt is the manifest file.

jar cfm Asteroids.jar AsteroidDriver.txt AsteroidDriver.class     AsteroidPanel.class AsteroidPanel$Key.class AsteroidPanel$Listener.class AsteroidPanel$1.class Asteroid.class Enemy.class Ship.class Hostile.class Bullet.class explosion.wav leaderboard.txt Title.png

Inside my AsteroidPanel this is the code I have for the KeyListener

```
private class Key extends KeyAdapter
{
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
  {
     //Does some stuff
  }
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
  {
     //Does some other stuff
  }
}
```

And the Run I/O gives me the error on this line inside my AsteroidPanel constructor.

```
addKeyListener(new Key());
```

Thanks in advance for any help I may receive, and I would like to reiterate that this is not a problem with the code itself as it works fine regularly, but a problem with me being clueless with jar files.

Comment: Unzip the Jar and double check the files exist.  Also, you should avoid placing classes within the default package, cause sometimes they don't load.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks a lot, I unzipped and they were not there, so I put them there and did jar cfm Asteroids.jar AsteroidDriver.txt *, and it works now.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I also made sure to put them in their own packages this time